# Continued issue using OrderBy and Take() with Included relations

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm aware of numerous issues raised on the EF7 Github repo, and these still appear to be present with the latest RC2 nightly builds.

The issue appears to be when using OrderBy and Take() when you're trying to Include relations within your query. I believe, according to previous issues raised on Github that the SQL generated within the join is incorrect and does not take into account the OrderBy. After reading replies, people have suggested using `Skip(0).Take(x)` as a workaround, but unfortunately in my scenario, this didn't work.

In my specific scenario, I'm querying a model based on an ancestor PK. So, in order to work around this, instead of passing the PK straight into the query, I've added the ancestor model to a `List<T>` and used the following code in the query instead:

Before (not working when Including nested relations): `p => p.examplePK == id`

After (appears to be working):
`p => myList.Select(c => c.myId).Contains(p.examplePK)`

I'm not entirely sure why the 2nd example works and I would be grateful of any info that can be given - could there potentially be some client side evaluation going on here instead? From what I gather, the 2nd example will be performing a SQL IN statement, will it not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's an `IN` clause. But I wouldn't try to work around issues that clearly *have* to be solved. Just wait until it's fixed. It's a PIA to remove these work-arounds later.

Comment: Anyone knows if there is an open GitHub issue that we can track the status of this bug?

Comment: I didn't raise one personally as I was unsure whether it was already covered as part of the numerous other issues raised regarding using Skip and Take together. Please raise one if you can't find a duplicate on GitHub.